# IIS: Use Application Request Routing for URL Rewrite outside of Default Website

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I'd like to do a URL rewrite in IIS where subdomain is rewritten. For example:

- `www.mycompany.com/api/v1.0` gets rewritten to `api1.mycompany.com`
- `www.mycompany.com/api/v2.0` gets rewritten to `api2.mycompany.com`

Note that I'd like to `rewrite` and not `redirect`, in other words, the URL in the browser remains `www.mycompany.com/api/v1.0` and `www.mycompany.com/api/v2.0`.

Any request that doesn't fit the patterns above should continue to be processed by `www.mycompany.com`.

My understanding is the URL Rewrite 2.0 module alone isn't enough to make this happen, so I installed Application Request Routing 3.0.  Here is the web.config for what I'm trying to do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="API v1.0" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^api/v1.0/(.*)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://api1.mycompany.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="API v2.0" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^api/v2.0/(.*)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://api2.mycompany.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Once I installed Application Request Routing, I was able to get this to work, but only if `www.mycompany.com` is the `Default Website` for IIS.  In other words, only if IIS is set up as so:

- Default Website (`www.mycompany.com`)

  - The web.config for this site is shown above
- `api1.mycompany.com`
- `api2.mycompany.com`

My problem is that `www.mycompany.com` cannot be the `Default Website` (the Default Website is reserved by another site on the server).  `www.mycompany.com` is just another web site just like `api1.mycompany.com` or `api2.mycompany.com`.  Is there any way to get this to work without `www.mycompany.com` being the `Default Website`?  Something like this?

- Default Website (some another non-related website)
- `www.mycompany.com`

  - The web.config for this site is as shown above
- `api1.mycompany.com`
- `api2.mycompany.com`

Comment: I wanted to do exactly this a few weeks back. I am not sure it can be done with URL Rewrite 2.0. It seems to me that the request is first passed to the rewrite module then based on the mappings it is passed to a new handle in the same app pool. URL Rewrite won't work the way you want if it needs to pass the request to another machine or between application pools. I would suggest making the question a bit more generic in case it is possible to achieve what you want with other tools on IIS. I voted this question up because I still hope I am wrong :D

Comment: Could you make changes on *C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config* ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand can you elaborate on what changes need to be done on applicatiohHost.config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can change the `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` config file, you can put your rewrite configuration inside it.

I test locally and it works under IIS8 and ARR 3.0.

[image: IIS configuration]

[image: Application Request Routing configuration]

My applicationHost.config file look like this :

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="API v1.0" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^api/v1.0/(.*)$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://api1.company.com/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="API v2.0" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^api/v2.0/(.*)$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://api2.company.com/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

<!-- ... --->

<webFarms>
    <applicationRequestRouting>
        <hostAffinityProviderList>
            <add name="Microsoft.Web.Arr.HostNameRoundRobin" />
            <add name="Microsoft.Web.Arr.HostNameMemory" />
        </hostAffinityProviderList>
    </applicationRequestRouting>
</webFarms>

<!-- ... --->

<system.applicationHost>
    <sites>
        <site name="Default Web Site" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <site name="company.com" id="2">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="company.com">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\tmp\company.com\www" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:www.company.com" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <site name="api1.company.com" id="3">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="api1.company.com">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\tmp\company.com\api1" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:api1.company.com" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <site name="api2.company.com" id="4">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="api2.company.com">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\tmp\company.com\api2" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:api2.company.com" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
    </sites>
</system.applicationHost>
```

[image: Final result]

Comment: I tried all of your steps but I can't get this to work.  Accessing api2.mycompany.com/books directly works, but trying to access it through www.mycompany.com/api/v2.0/books doesn't and I get a 404 response.  Is www.company.com in your example set up as a 'Default Web Site' in IIS (i.e. the one that comes by default in IIS)?

Comment: @JohnnyOshika It was not but I try again and it works the same, I also edit my answer. Maybe the application check something in url and fails (ASP.net routing). Could you try using simple resource such as `index.html` and see if it works ?

Comment: Wow, it worked when using simple html files.  There must be something in .Net that's routing things incorrectly.  Thank you!

Comment: I tried with a MVC and WebAPI application and it works. does your application make anything special with URL ? Try to use IIS Failed Request Tracing, it may help. Also try to set a breakpoint, maybe you will find uncatched exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, @Cyril Durand.  Our main app is MVC and our API is WebAPI, and I don't think we do anything special with URLs, but I could be mistaken because our apps have grown rather large over the years.  I'll try your suggestions to see where things are going wrong.